# How to determine the domain of $\ln(\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} - x)$?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I know that $$f:x\rightarrow ln(x)$$ is defined $$\forall x>\mathbb{R^{+*}}$$

But what happened when the argument of f is a function as "complicated" as$$\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} - x$$

Obviously we want
$$\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} - x > 0$$ but how do you solve that, I have no idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2-3x+2=\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}$ it follows $\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}$ is a real and positive number iff $\left|x-\frac{3}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2}$ i.e. iff $x$ belogs to $]-\infty,1[\cup]2,\infty[$. Also,  $x<\frac{2}{3}$ implies $-3x+2>0$ and $\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}>x$. For $x>2$ we get $$\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}<x-\frac{3}{2}<x.$$

Therefore, $\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}-x\right)$ is real iff $x<2/3$.

Comment: Why do you care that $\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}$ is positive? At that point in your reasoning, why must it not be zero?

Comment: Well, I was thinking the domain must be an open subset of $\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

We need $$\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} -x \gt 0$$
First we deal with the polynomial inside the square root, we know this polynomial must satisfy: \begin{eqnarray*} x^2-3x+2 &\ge&0\\
\iff x &\in& \{(-\infty;1]\cup[2;+\infty)\}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}  &\gt& x\\
x^2-3x+2&\gt& x^2\\
-3x+2 &\gt& 0\\
x&\lt&{2 \over 3}
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore $\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} -x \gt 0 \iff x\in \left\{\{(-\infty;1]\cup[2;+\infty)\}\bigcap (-\infty;{2 \over 3}]\right\}$ $$\iff x\lt\frac23$$

I also just realized your question is a little more general. In general when dealing with this situation you are trying to determine the domain on which your function, say $f(x)$, is defined. In order to find it you must take the intersection of the domains of each "component function" of $f(x)$.

In this example we had to first determine the domain of the square root function then determine the domain of the logarithm and take the intersection (notice we also implicitly determined the domain of the polynomials $x^2-3x+2$ and $x$, but we know these to be $\{-\infty;\infty\}$).
After you determine the domains of each "component function" then the intersection of all those domains will give you the domain of the function itself.